# Cannot access internal HDD error mounting /dev/sdb2 (NTFS signature is missing)

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10.

Specs:

- CPU: AMD A10-7700K
- APU: with Radeon(TM) R7 graphics × 4
- mobo: Gigabyte GA-f2a88xm-d3h
- RAM: 8GB
- HDDs: primary 128GB + secondary 2TB

Just after installation, I quick formatted secondary with NTFS file system and I started copying files. When I rebooted the system, the 2nd HDD was split into 3 partitions only two showing and when I tried access I got the following message:

```
Unable to access “372 GB Volume”
error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/mihalis/2604497C1A110D84: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/mihalis/2604497C1A110D84"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Please give me some help, I am trying for the first time use Ubuntu. I know nothing about.

Comment: try installing `ntfs-progs` or `ntfs-3g` using `apt-get install <pkg>`.

Comment: @AlexejMagura This package should be installed already. I guess the error message `NTFS signature is missing.` hints at the cause.

Comment: try updating Ubuntu (from the "update manager" that appears now and then). I think your issue was fixed

Answer (score 4):

Installing `ntfs-progs` or `ntfs-3g` should fix the issue you're experiencing.

I don't think it matters which of the two you install, you can the Ubuntu Documentation to see if one of the two is preferred.  I recall one of the two being preferred in [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G) but I don't recall which.

You can check to see if you already have them installed using:

```bash
dpkg -l | grep ntfs | grep ii # if there is no output, then you need to install
# one of the ntfs pacakges.
```

Example of how to install `ntfs-progs`

```bash
apt-get install ntfs-progs # make sure that you run this as root
```

To run something as root, prefix the command with `sudo`:

```bash
sudo apt-get install ntfs-progs
```

Answer (score 2):

The essential part seems to be the following error message:

```
exited with non-zero exit status 12: NTFS signature is missing.
```

As you should have no data on that partition in your case, you should simply create a new NTFS filesystem without quick format option.

In case you had data on the partition, you should scan the filesystem for errors, preferably on Windows.

---

## Reformatting a partition with NTFS

- **Option 1:** Terminal

  ```
  sudo mkntfs /dev/sdXY
  ```

  See the `mkntfs` [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/mkntfs.8.html) for details. Don't use `-f` or `-Q`.
- **Option 2:** Disks Utility (installed by default)

  [image]

  [image]
- **Option 3:** [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/)

  [image]

  See also: [Partitioning instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/CreatingPartitions).

Comment: `mkntfs` command saved my day.  Couldn't find an equivalent answer anywhere else!

Comment: Event though I had the volume formatted in Windows 10, re-formatting it in Ubuntu was the only solution that worked. No biggie as it wasn't the C drive.