# NTFS Signature is missing

Tags: ntfs, signature

So I got a new secondary hard drive caddy and formatted it to NTFS. I forgot to partition the drive after formatting, rebooted, and now I can't access the drive that has around 400 GB of data on it because the NTFS Signature is missing.

```
Error mounting...NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Says the same thing for sdb1. But I think the sdb2 has most, if not all of the copied data.

How do I retrieve my data back?

I read somewhere I can install ntfs-progs and it will fix the issue:
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447791/cannot-access-internal-hdd-error-mounting-dev-sdb2-ntfs-signature-is-missing/%22here%22)

Comment: So I managed to retrieve the data off a Windows OS by using a USB to SATA connector, but will take 3 hours to get back my data and get back on Trusty. But in the meantime, if anyone finds a solution, I welcome it.

Comment: can you type `sudo fdisk -l` in a terminal and show me the **full** output please? (copy **all** what you see in the terminal)

Comment: Often partition table may say NTFS, but PBR or partition boot sector must have the NTFS signature. Sometimes a fixBoot command or chkdsk in Windows or using testdisk to restore backup boot sector for partition may work.

Answer (score 3):

try to use this in terminal `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb2`